# Understanding Eigenface Face Recognition Algorithm Notations

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I have been reading the paper from Matthew A. Tusk and Alex Pentland

https://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~mturk/Papers/mturk-CVPR91.pdf

I got stuck in this part. I have a couple of questions.

[image]

Assume my images are 256 by 256.

1- What are G1,G2...Gm ? Row vectors? Column vectors? (1*65536) or (65536 * 1) ? Or are they 2D vectors (256*256)?

2- Then it says A = [ F1 F2 ... Fm] . Now I do not get this notation. Again A is what ? A matrix of matrices? or just a huge column/row vector?

Thanks

Comment: I think i found my answer here: http://www.vision.jhu.edu/teaching/vision08/Handouts/case_study_pca1.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

G1, G2... Gm are column vectors of length 65536.  The matrix A has columns that are the principal components.

Comment: Could you support us at - http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86832/ ?